# Объясните современный main

Tags: c++, auto

Недавно увидел следующий код, где `main` вызывает  более современный `main`:

```
constexpr auto modern_main(const auto argc, const auto argv) {
    // ...
    return auto{int{}};
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что он означает и откуда так много `auto`?

Comment: Давайте ссылку на этот код. И нет никакого современного `main` в рамках стандарта c++.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus я и не говорю, что это стандартный `main`. Стандартный `main` вызывает эту функцию. Кода нет в открытом доступе, чтобы дать ссылку

Comment: Просто в этом методе нет смысла, как минимум `contexpr` никогда не понадобиться, так как обычный main принимает аргументы в реальном времени, а не в время компиляции. А куча `auto` просто сахар для компилятора. Правда, никогда не видел такой `return` и не совсем понимаю что он должен делать. Типо `decltype`?

Comment: Просто выпендрёж. `constexpr` просто не сработает, первый `auto` превратится в `int`, `return auto{int{}};` — просто `return 0;`, потому что `int{}` дает `0` типа `int`, и `auto` тут — как рыбе зонтик... Типы `argc` и `argv` будут выведены из переданных параметров. Смысла никакого в этой функции нет, кроме "смотрите, а я еще вот так могу!" просто для того, чтоб показать, что могу...

Comment: В C++20 аргументы типа **auto** это сокращение шаблонной записи. [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template)

Comment: @AlexGlebe а остальные? можно полное объяснение в ответе?

Answer (score 2):

`contexpr` нужен для расчётов на этапе компиляции. Например: 
`constexpr auto x = "(4^2-9)/8+2/3"_solve;` 
`auto` позволяет определить тип переменной на этапе компиляции. Например:
`auto a = 0; // то же самое, что int a = 0` 
`int{}` - пустой инициализатор, инициализация по умолчанию. В данном случае это то же самое, что и 0. 
Теперь, надеюсь, вам всё понятно. И да, называть "современным main'ом" какую-то ересь не стоит.